# Trouble arranging React components within the id="root" element when using the Vite development tool

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5, vite

When attempting to organize components in React, I noticed that only half of the browser is being displayed. I applied CSS to the body element as follows:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: var(--violet);
  transition: all 3ms ease;
  color: var(--write);
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  display: flex;
}
```

Additionally, I incorporated Bootstrap, using a container-fluid class for the navbar. However, despite these efforts, the navbar still occupies only half of the page.**body is taking the whole browser but the problem is with id=root it takes only half of the page**

In addition to my previous attempts, I experimented with styling the id=root element by setting its width to 100vw. While this caused the navbar to occupy the full width of the browser, I have reservations about the effectiveness of this method. When the browser is resized to a smaller screen or in a responsive mode, the navbar continues to occupy only half of the page.

Please let me know if you have any recommendations or suggestions for achieving a more consistent and responsive layout for the navbar in React while using Bootstrap.

Comment: How did you bootstrap your app? If you used [`create-vite`](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/create-vite), the React template comes with styling for the `#root` element.